# What is the sequence of events firing off in asp.net Gridview control?

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview, sequence

I use GridViews pretty often and sometimes I get confused to where to put certain code. What is the sequence that events are fired off including all page events?

**Edited:**
I really am also trying to understand what happens between the page and the Gridview. Do the events ever cross? Or do all page events occur at once then all Gridview events occur? And not just GridViews, any control - but mostly page and GridView interaction.

Comment: Really, try to add a System.Diagnostics.Debug.Writeline for every event as in my answer. Add a gridview to the page in design-time, but really also try to add one during Page_PreRender. This will really give you a good view on what's going on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView1_Load");
}
protected void GridView1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView1_DataBinding");
}
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView1_DataBound");
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView1_RowDataBound");
}
```

Comment: This will come in handy for other classes you will encounter. Doing it this way is the ONLY way you can be sure the events are firing. Microsoft -can say it does- but how do you KNOW for sure? lol

Answer (score 7):

If you're refering to the Page Life Cycle, you can find an overview [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Summary of the life cycle is:

**Page request**

The page request occurs before the page life cycle begins. When the page is requested by a user, ASP.NET determines whether the page needs to be parsed and compiled (therefore beginning the life of a page), or whether a cached version of the page can be sent in response without running the page.

**Start**

In the start step, page properties such as Request and Response are set. At this stage, the page also determines whether the request is a postback or a new request and sets the IsPostBack property. Additionally, during the start step, the page's UICulture property is set.

**Page initialization**

During page initialization, controls on the page are available and each control's UniqueID property is set. Any themes are also applied to the page. If the current request is a postback, the postback data has not yet been loaded and control property values have not been restored to the values from view state.

**Load**

During load, if the current request is a postback, control properties are loaded with information recovered from view state and control state.

**Validation**

During validation, the Validate method of all validator controls is called, which sets the IsValid property of individual validator controls and of the page.

**Postback event handling**

If the request is a postback, any event handlers are called.

**Rendering**

Before rendering, view state is saved for the page and all controls. During the rendering phase, the page calls the Render method for each control, providing a text writer that writes its output to the OutputStream of the page's Response property.

**Unload**

Unload is called after the page has been fully rendered, sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded. At this point, page properties such as Response and Request are unloaded and any cleanup is performed.

As for the GridView events, they can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993231.aspx

Gridview Control Events

Answer (score 0):

There's a longer list at [ASP.NET 2.0 Event Order](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2010/12/aspnet-20-event-order.html) (note this is for 2.0).